# css - triangle borders 100% of screen

Tags: html, css, border

**Desired result:**

A CSS solution where I have a container with `width: 100%;`, and above and below the container, I have triangles attached that create a parallelogram. The triangles should cover the entire width of the screen.

**Problem**

I tried with `transform`, but that also transforms the text inside the container, so that doesn't work to create the desired form. Right now I'm trying with 2 divs, 1 above and 1 under the container, and with `border-right` css property. The problem here is that it doesn't accept percentages.

**Code**

HTML:

```
<div class="triangleUP"></div>
<article class="blue">
    Lorem ipsum (times 200)
</article>
<div class="triangleDOWN"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.triangleUP {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 250px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1920px solid #344cd0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.blue{
    background-color:#344cd0;
    color:white;
}
.triangleDOWN{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 250px solid #344cd0;
    border-right: 1920px solid transparent;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0g02gwL2/)

I know that with jQuery I could easily manipulate the property, but I'd prefer to keep it CSS only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution here would be to use `100vw` which is 100% of the viewport width. Here is a [table of current browser support.](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw)

New CSS:

```
.triangleUP {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 250px solid transparent;
border-right: 100vw solid #344cd0;
overflow:hidden;
}
.blue{
    background-color:#344cd0;
    color:white;
}
.triangleDOWN{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 250px solid #344cd0;
    border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
}
```

Result:
[image: I hope this is what you wanted it to look like]

Comment: Mozilla firefox, IE and Chrome all give a distorted result, sadly.

Comment: Sorry then. could you specify what you want the element to look like? Also another possible option for a parallelogram is to have one div inside another, with the first being a skew transform and then the one inside being a skew transform in the opposite direction and degrees.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the triangle to be responsive but with a set width which is not 100% of the screen, you can use calc.

```css
.bg{
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.bg:after{
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: calc(100vh - 50px) calc(100vw - 50px) 0 0;
  border-color: #fedbda transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">

</div>
```